# Excel: Show second data set within each column

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I want to add flavor to an existing column chart which displays sales data per region (NY, HK, LND) for each month starting with January until December. In each region, there are several persons contributing to that total number of each column.

That is why I want the average across the sales representatives within each region to be displayed in each corresponding column, ideally as a dotted line as shown below in the picture (Link desired graph).

I have tried several things but not found a solution. I hope my little drawing makes my desire a little clearer. Can somebody help me or give me some good keywords to google for? Let me know if I can provide additional info.

Here is the link to a picture of the desired Graph:

[image]

Update 1: Thank to your great replies, I am getting closer to the desired result. I have now inserted line charts with markers and no line.

Two things are missing: First, I'd like to have the number within the marker. Second, the average markers should appear within the corresponding column bar of the same city. I haven't found a way to help excel identify the link between the total data rows and the average data set for each region, e.g. the green dot should appear in the yellow Manilla bar. Do you people have an idea how to do that? I have attached a chart from the internet with correct dots positioning.

[my current chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpGhr.png)

[chart from internet with correct dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMsN0.png)

Comment: Can you show some actual spreadsheet data? What have you already tried?

Comment: Hi Harry, sure! How can I insert an Image in the comments? 
I tried to add the average per region data to the chart, but then it was just added as a line across the whole chart instead just within a small line within the respective column bars.

Comment: Plot the second series of averages as a line chart showing markers but no line, and choose a suitable marker which looks like a horizontal line, or use a custom marker based on an image you choose.

Comment: You want to [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1674999/edit) instead of adding information in comments

Comment: @AdamV : Thank you, great help. Do you know how I can set the marker within the corresponding regional column bar?

Comment: Did you check the Pivot Chart? Did you want to combine 2 table in 1 chart?